# post page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In the wordpress reading settings, where you set your "blog" page to post page,

even if I create a custom template for the blog - or add addition text/custom fields etc.
nothing seems to appear....

as far i understood , those will be ignored... as it is set static...

is there a other way, to create a custom page ("blog"), where you can add all those post into this page , style them, add text as well

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking, how can I make a page of posts then there are many answers to this question. I personally ended up using these 2 plugins:

Pages Posts (which lets you present posts of a specific category or tag on a page)
Simply Exclude (Lets you selectively exclude categories and tags from page)

both can be installed via the plugins search